# New Installed Extension show 404 Error Page not found in backend

Tags: magento-1.7

We installed new extension in magento 1 but it show 404 page not found in backend. I try log out login/cache clear but nothing happened

Comment: Make sure compilation is disabled on site.

Answer (score 0):

First: You must make sure that module support your magento version.

Second: Disable magento compilation by configure: System -> Tools -> Compilation and click on the Disable button.